# Redirect example.com/! to homepage?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

One our clients has placed an unsolicited testimonial of our site to their site.
That is all fine except for one thing, they linked our site like this: `http://example.com/!` which results in to page not found. Is there a way I can redirect that link to our site properly?

Comment: And you site is `http://example.com`? Have them fix their links?

Comment: that is the ideal quick solution but as it is unsolicited it's a little awkward to ask them to edit their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\!$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It simply but effectively rewrites all URLs containing a "!" character at the end.

In simpler words: if the URL ends with a "!", it will be rewritten to the same URL without that trailing "!". This rewrite even takes care of "example.com/index/here!" and rewrites it to "example.com/index/here" which makes even more sense to avoid.

Guess that's what you're looking for? ;)